# Net-SNMP/snpmd pass script not working with daemon, but with debug mode

Tags: debian, net-snmp, snmpd

We are running snmpd on Debian 8 since many years. Since very recently our "pass" script is not recognized anymore when we run the daemon. When we run snmpd in debug mode it works fine.

Script for test:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$2"
echo "String"
echo "TEST $1"
exit 0
```

Result when daemon is running:

```
~# snmpget -v2c -c public localhost enterprises.00119.1
P-133-MIB::PTRK = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

Result when debug foreground mode is running:

```
snmpd -f -Le -Ducd-snmp/pass -Drun
~# snmpget -v2c -c public localhost enterprises.00119.1
P-133-MIB::PTRK = STRING: "TEST -g
```

This is the entry in /etc/snmpd/snmpd.conf:

`pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.00119 /root/test`

All files are chmod 0777.

Worked smooth until a recent new install + apt-get update/upgrade on a machine that had exactly the same config. We have to stick to Debian 8.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

RESOLVED:

the pass script must not be in /root

another folder like /usr/local/etc works (have not tried others).